# Could not load type in Custom Profile provider

Tags: c#, console-application, asp.net-profiles

I am writing a small console application in C# that references a custom assembly that implements custom .net Profile provider. I have added the following sections to my app.config file which references the custom class and assembly.

```xml
<system.web>
<profile defaultProvider="MyCompanyProfileProvider" inherits="MyCompany.Web.User.GenericProfile" automaticSaveEnabled="false">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="MyCompanyProfileProvider" connectionStringName="defaultDatabase" applicationName="/myApplication" type="MyCompany.Web.ProfileProvider, MyCompany.Web"/>
    </providers>
    <properties>
        <add name="JobRoleId" type="System.Int32"/>
        <add name="LastCompetencyId" type="System.Int32" defaultValue="0"/>
        <add name="MixSettings" type="System.Xml.XmlDocument"/>
    </properties>
</profile></system.web>
```

However when I run the app in debug mode I get the following error as if it is looking in the System.Web assembly rather than one specified in the app.config file.

***Could not load type 'MyCompany.Web.User.GenericProfile' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.***

I have a local web app that also uses the assembly and custom Profile provider and that work without any problems.  I have checked the referenced assembly is  being copied to the output directory.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this and it was so simple!! (He says after hours of searching and debugging).

I just had to tell explicitly say in which assembly my custom provider resided. I thought I only had to do this when specifying the type when adding the provider.

However you need to define when defining your profile in the inherits attribute.  Like so:

Before:

```xml
<profile defaultProvider="MyCompanyProfileProvider"
         inherits="MyCompany.Web.User.GenericProfile"
         automaticSaveEnabled="false">
```

After:

```xml
<profile defaultProvider="MyCompanyProfileProvider" 
         inherits="MyCompany.Web.User.GenericProfile, MyCompany.Web" 
         automaticSaveEnabled="false">
```

Hope this helps somebody else in the future with the same problem.

Comment: +1 - This helped me to get my NUnit tests working. Everthing was working fine while running my MVC4 application, but the unit tests were failing. Make sure this change is included in the app.config file referenced by any unit test modules.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the extra space behind the comma where you specify your class and assembly, but I don't think that will fix it.

Your app is looking up your custom class in the System.Web assembly, which is very strange.

I'd use [fuslogvw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(VS.71).aspx) to get more details on the failure.

Comment: Tried both suggestions and still no further forward. Fuslogvw gave me no decent information to track the problem down further.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution saved my sorry a*se after I WASTED DAYS of my precious time chasing down this problem.  As usual, I have WASTED DAYS fighting Microsoft's products instead of the actual IT problems I need to solve themselves.  My App.Config lines now look thus and it seems to work fine:

```
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider" inherits="SmartTariffs_V13.ProfileCommon, SmartTariffs_V13">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
```

Where SmartTariffs_V13 is the name of the Project and SmartTariffs_V13.ProfileCommon is the name of the .cs file within that project.  I found this works without adding your "automaticSaveEnabled" tag, but hey ho ...